# Error when save Vietnamese font in playframework2 + java + Mysql Workbrench

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, mysql-workbench

I use Play2.0.4 + Java + Mysql Workbench on Ubuntu :)

When i add

```
Em xin cảm ơn // = Thank you very much
```

This error appeared :

```
[PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Incorrect string value: '\xE1\xBA\xA3m \xC6...' for column 'description' at row 1]]
```

and mark error `user.save()`

```
public static void create (Users user){
            user.save(); // mark this line
}
```

and if i changed password, it display like that :

```
Em xin c?m ?n
```

I try config databse collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` and `utf8_general_ci` or `latin_general_ci` but it didn't work.

Any ideal or help in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh ~.~ I change my database to `utf8-defaultcollation` and it worked :) hope this help for other language :)